# Create a Table in SnowFlake dynamically (Using JSON data from the staging area)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Is there a way to create a table( with columns) dynamically by using the JSON file from the staging area?

I used the comman: 'copy into TableName from @StageName;'

This put all the different rows in my json file into a single column.

[image]

However, I want different columns. For example column1 should be "IP", column 2 should be "OS" and so on.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented the same thing in my project.

So its a 2 step process.

1st Step - Create a stage table with variant data type table and copy into table from stage - which I can see you have already done that.

2nd Step - Either create a table or a view(since snowflake is superfast, View is the way to go for this dynamic extract of JSON data) which will read the data directly from this variant column, something like this

```
create or replace view schema.vw_tablename copy grants as  
SELECT
v:Duration::int Duration,
v:Connectivity::string Connectivity
...
from public.tablename
```

if your JSON has an array of structure, use below

```
create or replace view schema.vw_tablename copy grants as  
SELECT
v:Duration::int Duration,
v:Connectivity::string Connectivity,
f.value:Time::int as Event_Time,
from public.tablename,
table(flatten(v:arrayname)) f
```

Comment: what if it's the nested json file of big size? Then step 1 itself won't be possible due to size limit on variant data type. Any workaround?

Comment: Nested JSON is not a problem with snowflake.. You can go as deep as you want.

Comment: About the size limit, individual json upto 20 MB is supported i believe, if the JSON is bigger than 20MB, I would suggest to split the JSON on some structure and make it smaller!